# Where would I give credit to an MIT licensed project, in an iOS app?

Tags: mit, attribution

I would like to include a pod that I found on cocoa pods and its an animation of a button. It is licensed under MIT licence:  https://cocoapods.org/pods/DynamicButton

In the licence it states:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Do I include this in my code or do I have to dedicate a specific view to it, in settings or something of the sort?

Comment: MIT defines the word Software's meaning for us in [`this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")`] paragraph, and obviously MIT paragraph starts with "this software" (not "the Software") and puts the quotes around "`Software`" alone (meaning, wherever "Software" is mentioned from that point on, their original content was meant) and later MIT asks "substantial portions of the Software" to attribute, but remember that Software is their original work (i.e. if you got binary from them, then you must attribute where ever you use that binary, else just ensure you compile/Uglify)

Comment: While some jurisdictions may define the default meaning of "The Software"; What is the definition of "this" in jurisdiction? MIT License calls the entire original content "this software" and defines "Software" to mean same as that. And although very short, MIT does undeniably specify what "Software" means, and excludes default jurisdiction meanings (which was the right choice, in many countries, jurisdiction meanings differ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To satisfy the legal requirement you only need to keep the license in your source code, such as in a LICENSE file or as a comment block in the source code itself.

To be nice, you can also display the license information somewhere that users can see it.

But if you display the license information to users too verbosely, you might be called "an unmitigated jerk", as I have been, in the case of my "pngcrush" application (which I have [recently modified](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmt/news/?source=navbar) to be less verbose by default).

Comment: "an unmitigated jerk" .... +1 for the good clean laugh!

Comment: what if your app is not open-sourced? Would this work with commercial apps?